# CreateRestrictedToken - SidsToDisable

Tags: python, windows, api

I am learning Python security (Windows API) and particularly trying to start up notepad.exe as a restricted user using the `CreateRestrictedToken` API. Currently when I execute the script, notepad.exe starts up with the `DISABLE_MAX_PRIVILEGE` (0x1) as expected.

In addition to `DISABLE_MAX_PRIVILEGE` (0x1), I would like to disable some SIDs, such as Administrators (S-1-5-32-544), Authenticated Users (S-1-5-11), and Console Logon (S-1-2-1). I have attempted to disable the Administrators SID; however, it fails with the following error:

```
TypeError: 'PySID' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

There seems to be a structure in the `SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES`, but I'm not quite sure how to put it together.

My Python build is x64 version 2.7.4.

```
import win32process
import win32job
import time
import win32event
import win32security
import win32api
from random import randint

ph = win32process.GetCurrentProcess()
th = win32security.OpenProcessToken(ph,win32security.TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS)

admins = win32security.ConvertStringSidToSid("S-1-5-32-544")[0]

token = win32security.CreateRestrictedToken(th, 1, admins, None, None)

startup = win32process.STARTUPINFO()
(hProcess, hThread, processId, threadId) = win32process.CreateProcessAsUser(token, "C:\\Windows\\Notepad.exe", None, None, None, True, win32process.CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB, None, None, startup)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SidsToDisable` parameter of PyWin32's [`CreateRestrictedToken`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/win32security__CreateRestrictedToken_meth.html) takes a [`PySID_AND_ATTRIBUTES`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/PySID_AND_ATTRIBUTES.html). This is a sequence of `(PySID, Attributes)` tuples. The attributes are ignored in this case, so use 0. For example:

```
import os
import win32process
import win32security

token = win32security.OpenProcessToken(win32process.GetCurrentProcess(),
                                       win32security.TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS)

disabled_sids = [(win32security.CreateWellKnownSid(sidt), 0)
                 for sidt in [win32security.WinBuiltinAdministratorsSid,
                              win32security.WinAuthenticatedUserSid]]

# WinConsoleLogonSid (81) requires Windows 8.
# Use the string SID instead.
disabled_sids.append(
    (win32security.ConvertStringSidToSid("S-1-2-1"), 0))

token_r = win32security.CreateRestrictedToken(
            token, win32security.DISABLE_MAX_PRIVILEGE,
            disabled_sids, None, None)

notepad_path = os.path.join(os.environ['SystemRoot'], 'notepad.exe') 
startup = win32process.STARTUPINFO()

(hProcess, hThread,
 processId, threadId) = win32process.CreateProcessAsUser(
    token_r, notepad_path, None, None, None,
    True, win32process.CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB, None, None, startup)
```